# Better way to write this linq query Pt2

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In response to this question:

[Better way to write this linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620389/better-way-to-write-this-linq-query)

How would i build a dynamic query following the same pattern in that thread?

For example, the signature of the method changes to:

```
     public List<PeopleSearchList> GetPeople(string filter, string searchType, string searchOption)
    {

        return a new List of type PeopleSearchList

    }
```

So now i am not returning a single array of "Firstnames" etc i am returning a custom class.

The class would look like this:

```
public class PeopleSearchList
{
    public String IdentityCode { get; set; }
    public String Firstname { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public Int32 LoanCount { get; set; }
    public String Group { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You could use the [Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

Just thought i would post the solution for others to see.

```
 public List<PeopleSearchList> GetPeople(string filter, string searchType, string searchOption)
    {
        IQueryable<Person> query = _context.People;

        PropertyInfo property = typeof (Person).GetProperty(searchType);
        MethodInfo method = typeof (string).GetMethod(searchOption, new[] {typeof (string)});

        query = query.Where(WhereExpression(property, method, filter));

        IQueryable<PeopleSearchList> resultQuery = query.Select(p => new PeopleSearchList
                                                                         {
                                                                             Firstname = p.Firstname,
                                                                             Group = p.Level.Year,
                                                                             IdentityCode = p.IdentityCode,
                                                                             LoanCount = p.Loans.Count(),
                                                                             Surname = p.Surname
                                                                         }
            ).OrderBy(p => p.Surname);

        return resultQuery.ToList();

    }

 Expression<Func<Person, bool>> WhereExpression(PropertyInfo property, MethodInfo method, string filter)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "o");
        var propExpr = Expression.Property(param, property);
        var methodExpr = Expression.Call(propExpr, method, Expression.Constant(filter));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(methodExpr, param);
    }
```